# jQuery call a function that executes with click

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, onchange

I have a jQuery function like this:

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function (event) 
{ 
    ...
```

This works 100%. the function adds a row to my table when the user clicks the button add row.

Is there any way to call this function without clicking the button.

For instance, when the user enters a qty, on change I want to call the function so new row is added automatically without the user clicking add row?

Maybe two listenerrs? one for on click addrow and one for onchange qty?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 3):

you mean:

```
$("#addrow").trigger("click");
```

or

```
$("#addrow").click();
```

Comment: For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event handler calls event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired, use .triggerHandler() instead.

Comment: Thanks, not quite understanding. the addrow click works great. I want to call the same functiion when I have an onchange event. so in input qty, an onchange event that calls the function (that is executed when user clicks addrow)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
//jQuery
$( "#addrow" ).click();
$( "#addrow" ).trigger( "click" );

//javascript
document.getElementById("addrow").click();
```

Reference

Trigger : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Click : http://api.jquery.com/click/

**EDITED CODE**

```
            $('#qty').change(function(){
                $( "#addrow" ).trigger( "click" );
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, not quite understanding. the addrow click works great. I want to call the same functiion when I have an onchange event. so in input qty, an onchange event that calls the function (that is executed when user clicks addrow)

Comment: Thanks. how does this get triggered by the addrow button click and the qty change event? Apologies for my ignorance but will the addrow click only be called if the qty changes? am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a native event not a custom one, so i would suggest

```
$("#addrow").triggerHandler("click");
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)